# Is it possible Django model filter by LogEntry by user added in ModelAdmin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am working with a blog site. I want to add some feature that like admin filter post can modify only that user added. I want to use Django builtin LogEntry model.

Any can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `ModelAdmin`'s `get_queryset` method along the following lines:

from django.contrib.admin.models import ADDITION
from django.contrib import admin

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(MyModel)
        qs = qs.filter(id__in=list(
                 LogEntry.objects.filter(content_type=ct, 
                                         action_flag=admin.models.ADDITION, 
                                         user=request.user)\
                                 .values_list('object_id', flat=True)))
        return qs
```

This will narrow down the objects the admin has access to the ones created by the currently logged in user.